# Android listview clicking on item multiple times

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with several items. When clicking on an item, an Activity is opened. However, when I click fast several times on the item, the activity, asociated with it, is opened several times. How to open the item only once?

I use the following code:

```
private OnItemClickListener newsfeedClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyObject newsfeed = adapter.getItem(position);
        onNewsfeedClick(newsfeed);
    }
};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsfeed, container, false);
    ...
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsfeeds);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(newsfeedClickHandler);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
    return view;
}
private void onNewsfeedClick(MyObject newsfeed) {
    Intent intent = createIntent(newsfeed);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Define boolean isClicked = false;
and check if(!isClicked){isClicked = true; // and start your activity}

Comment: put the lauch mode to     android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to prevent calls to the ListView items would be to (obviously) disable the `OnItemClickListener`:

```
private void onNewsfeedClick(MyObject newsfeed) {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
    Intent intent = createIntent(newsfeed);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Re-set the listener at `onResume`, when this activity is visible again.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(newsfeedClickHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a boolean value say `isItemClicked` and reset it when you return back to the listview.

```
private boolean isItemClicked;
  private OnItemClickListener newsfeedClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      if (!isItemClicked) {
        isItemClicked = true;
        MyObject newsfeed = adapter.getItem(position);
        onNewsfeedClick(newsfeed);
      }
    }
  };

  private void resetIsItemClicked() {
    isItemClicked = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent multiple clicks on ListView Items, add the following code in your listview click listener:

```
if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTimeListViewItem < 1000){
    return;
}
```