# Reenabling a Long Click on Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent, onlongclicklistener

I have a map, where the user has the option to long click and add a marker (it opens the new activity with intent, so he can add info about the marker). I had a problem with multiple long clicks, opening multiple new activities. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980737/android-listview-clicking-on-item-multiple-times) solution, and was able to block multiple long clicks, but the resetting long clicks after the user has opened new activity did not work for me.

My maps fragment:

```
 //Add marker on long click
 mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng arg0) {
         // disabling long click
         mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(null);

         RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(arg0.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(arg0.longitude) + "&key=myKey";

         // Request a string response from the provided URL.
         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(String response) {
                 try {
                     JSONArray jObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRestaurantActivity.class);

                      for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                          String componentName = new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getJSONArray("types").getString(0);
                          if (componentName.equals("postal_code") || componentName.equals("locality") || componentName.equals("street_number") || componentName.equals("route")
                                                    || componentName.equals("neighborhood") || componentName.equals("sublocality") || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_2")
                                                    || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_1") || componentName.equals("country")) {
                                                intent.putExtra(componentName, new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getString("short_name"));
                           }
                      }

                       intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                       intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        int x = 1;
    }
 });
 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
 queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround - I used ProgressDialog to disable user to longclick twice:

```
 GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener onMapLongClickListener =new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loading. Please wait...",true);

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(arg0.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(arg0.longitude) + "&key=myKey";

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRestaurantActivity.class);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                            String componentName = new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getJSONArray("types").getString(0);
                            if (componentName.equals("postal_code") || componentName.equals("locality") || componentName.equals("street_number") || componentName.equals("route")
                              || componentName.equals("neighborhood") || componentName.equals("sublocality") || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_2")
                              || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_1") || componentName.equals("country")) {
                                intent.putExtra(componentName, new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getString("short_name"));
                            }
                        }

                        intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        pd.cancel();

                        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onMapLongClickListener);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.cancel();
                }
            });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a listener for the long click, eg:

```
 GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener onMapLongClickListener =new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(null);

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(arg0.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(arg0.longitude) + "&key=myKey";

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRestaurantActivity.class);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                            String componentName = new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getJSONArray("types").getString(0);
                            if (componentName.equals("postal_code") || componentName.equals("locality") || componentName.equals("street_number") || componentName.equals("route")
                              || componentName.equals("neighborhood") || componentName.equals("sublocality") || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_2")
                              || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_1") || componentName.equals("country")) {
                                intent.putExtra(componentName, new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getString("short_name"));
                            }
                        }

                        intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onMapLongClickListener);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    int x = 1;
                }
            });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    };
```

and at your onMapReady, setListener for onMapLongClickListener:

```
 mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onMapLongClickListener);
```

You can disable  LongClicklistener as per the previous code you are using and add the listener when you got response, Code are included in my **onMapLongClick()**, you just have to copy the code and add listener on onMapReady() as i mentioned above.

Let me know whether it solves your problem or not.

Comment: Thank you Sachin. I will try this tonight and let you know, and accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: I tried this solution, but unfortunately it did not work. Since this method is in onMapReady, I have added this:                         `queue.add(stringRequest);
                    }
                };
                mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onMapLongClickListener);` Also, this line of code gives `mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onMapLongClickListener);` gives error - not initialized.